# Vuex state not updating

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I am trying to render different UIs depending on whether a user is a retailer or not. I think I have mostly everything correct, but when the app initializes, I want to check whether the user is a retailer or not (This dispatches the `checkAuth` action).

I try running the following to get the value of the `isRetailer` property from Firebase.

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid + '/isRetailer').once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val()
```

Then I dispatch some actions based on the result. For some reason, the `isRetailer` part of my Vuex state is not updating from false even when the users `isRetailer` property is true.

I'm not really sure why but I'm guessing it has something to do w/ my firebase reference. My full code is below. Thanks!

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'

const authentication = {
    state: {
        isAuthed: false,
        authId: '',
        isRetailer: false
    },
    mutations: {
        authUser (state, user) {
            state.isAuthed = true;
            state.authId = user.uid;
        },
        notAuthed (state) {
            state.isAuthed = false;
            state.authId = '';
            state.isRetailer = false
        },
        isRetailer (state) {
            state.isRetailer = true
        },
        isNotRetailer (state) {
            state.isRetailer = false
        }
    },
    actions: {
        checkUser (context, user) {

            if (!user.uid) {

                // Do nothing.

            } else if (firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid + '/isRetailer').once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val()) === true) {

                context.commit('authUser', user);

                context.commit('isRetailer');

            } else {

                context.commit('authUser', user);

                context.commit('isNotRetailer');
            };
        },
        signOut (context) {
            context.commit('notAuthed')
        },
        setRetailer (context, payload) {

            // Set retailer info in Firebase.

            var uid = payload.user.uid;
            firebase.database().ref('/users/' + uid).set({
                name: payload.name,
                email: payload.email,
                location: payload.retailerLocation,
                isRetailer: payload.isRetailer
            });  

        },
        setNewUser (context, payload) {

            // Sets a user in firebase w/ a isRetailer value of false. 

            var uid = payload.user.uid;

            firebase.database().ref('/users/' + uid).set({
                name: payload.name,
                email: payload.email,
                isRetailer: payload.isRetailer
            });
        }
    },
    getters: {}
};

export default authentication;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because you have given same name to mutation and state variable: `isRetailer`, I don't have any reference right now, but this might be the case for mutation not triggering, You can try once by setting your mutation by different name such as:

```
mutations: {
    ...
    ...
    setIsRetailer (state) {
        state.isRetailer = true
    },
    isNotRetailer (state) {
        state.isRetailer = false
    }
},
```

and use this in actions:

```
actions: {
    checkUser (context, user) {
        ...
        ...

            context.commit('authUser', user);
            context.commit('setIsRetailer');

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I took a look at Vuex tools and it looked like the code was going right to the second `else` block. I changed from `=== true` to `!== false` and now it seems to be working fine.